# Телеграм бот не может запостить сообщение

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Я хочу сделать лог канал для своего бота.
Код:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("xxxxxx")
log_ch = -1380216357

@bot.message_handler(commands="start")
def start_hndlr(msg: telebot.types.Message):
    bot.send_message(log_ch, f"#user{msg.from_user.id} запустил бота")

bot.polling()
```

Когда я отправляю боту в лс /start, он выдает ошибку

```
2021-01-26 13:43:23,256 (__init__.py:510 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: chat not found"
```

У бота отключена приватность групп, права администратора есть, канал приватный

Добавлено:
Клиент для телеграмма Telegraph неправильно определяет id групп, проблема была в нем

Comment: у чата реально отрицательный номер?

Comment: @Эникейщик, в апи написано что чаты должны быть с минусом (я пробовал и без него, все равно не работает)

Comment: `log_ch` разве не должна быть строкой?

Comment: string либо int по оф. документации

Comment: В настройках бота у @BotFather разрешите вступление бота в группы. Добавьте бота в группу.  Это сделано?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, да, сделано

Comment: И несколько раз

Answer (score 2, accepted):

айди группы или канала начинается с `-100`..

для получения айди вы можете воспользоваться следующим кодом:

```
# Отладка
import logging

logger = telebot.logger
telebot.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

- добавьте бота в группу/канал
- запустите бота
- напишите сообщение в группу/канал (со своего аккаунта)

в консоли вы увидите похожее:

> (apihelper.py:111 PollingThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "The server
> returned:
> 'b'{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":389450237,\n"channel_post":{"message_id":24,"sender_chat":{"id":-100...,"title":"test
> bot channel","type":"channel"},"chat":{"id":-100...,"title":"test bot
> channel","type":"channel"},"date":1611661758,"text":"asd"}}]}''

где `chat":{"id":-100...` и будет айди вашего канала/группы.

Либо вы можете отправить сообщение от своего аккаунта, нажать на него правой кнопкой -> Копировать ссылку на сообщение.
`https://t.me/c/136.../25` значение между `c/` и `/**` и есть айди, просто добавьте в начало `-100`.